# Unable to add cookie from application tab in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Does anyone know why I can't add a cookie from the application tab in Google Chrome?

[image]

This is my cookie browser settings
[image]

My Google Chrome version is 98.0.4758.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I have tried to check the changelog from their blog but nothing mentioned about cookie here (https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2022/02/stable-channel-update-for-desktop_14.html)

the only solution I can apply is using the console tab and setting the cookie from javascript code like this

```
document.cookie = "this-is-cooke=value"
```

***UPDATED***

It seems the issue was fixed, I updated my Google Chrome to version 101.0.4951.54 and I can modify the cookie value now.

There is no cookie issue mentioned in the release note https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2022/04/stable-channel-update-for-desktop_26.html. But at least the bug was fixed. Thank you, the case is closed.